# QGIS Raster Calculator dialog doesn't resemble that in documentation

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I'm very new to QGIS.  Raster Calculator looks (from online sources) like it ought to have all kinds of buttons and fields.  Mine is rather stripped down.  I have two rasters open, and I just want to divide their values.  Is there a plugin missing or something? (ps -- it doesn't change if I select the rasters)

[image: My Raster Calculator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like *a* raster calculator. Probably from the processing toolbox (GRASS maybe?).

There is a QGIS raster calculator in the **Raster** pull-down menu.

[image: QGIS raster calculator]

Comment: Ah -- I was taking it from the toolbox (Raster/General/Raster Calculator) -- thanks!